# Insert Result of query into existing table in SQL server database

Tags: sql-server

I don't use SQL so often therefore it doesn't seem time efficient to figure out solution on my own.

I want to insert result of this query

```
select 
    zadavatel, advertiser 
from 
    DATA_2015_CZ_CLEAN_v03 
where 
    Advertiser is null and zadavatel is not null
group by 
    zadavatel, advertiser
```

into table which has these columns [Zadavatel],[Advertiser],[Note]

Further from this query above advertiser is null but I want to change Advertiser value to be equal zadavatel value. SO row by row obviously. Note is nullable column.

Make it more understandable result of query might look like.

```
Zadavatel Advertiser
Coca-Cola  Null
Pepsi-cola Null
```

Table Zadavatel might look like this

```
Zadavatel   Advertiser  Note
Mercedes    Mercedes    Null
Ferrero ltd Ferrero     Null
```

Updated Zadavatel should look like this

```
Zadavatel   Advertiser  Note
 Mercedes     Mercedes    Null
 Ferrero ltd  Ferrero     Null
 Coca-Cola    Coca-Cola   Null
 Pepsi-Cola   Pepsi-Cola  Null
```

Important thing to mention is that only from query results advertiser should take zadavatel values . As You see in final table Ferrero ltd and Ferrero don't match which is already a result of manual processing

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert into a Temp table by adding INTO.....

```
SELECT zadavatel, COALESCE(advertiser, zadavatel), NULL
INTO #TEMPTABLE
FROM DATA_2015_CZ_CLEAN_v03
```

The COALESCE handles if advertiser IS NULL and uses zadavatel instead in that instance.
Not sure what you want in Notes.

If you wanted it into a permananet table and you have the table defined correctly....

```
INSERT INTO YourTable 
(Field1, Field2, Field3)
SELECT zadavatel, COALESCE(advertiser, zadavatel), NULL
FROM DATA_2015_CZ_CLEAN_v03
```

Answer (score 1):

bit late but it can help you as well

```
USE tempdb
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#Data1') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #Data1
    (
    ID INT IDENTITY
    ,Valor1 VARCHAR(100)
    ,Valor2 VARCHAR(100)
    )
END
GO
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#Data2') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #Data2
    (
    ID INT IDENTITY
    ,Valor1 VARCHAR(100)
    ,Valor2 VARCHAR(100)
    ,Note VARCHAR(100)
    )
END
INSERT INTO #Data1 (Valor1) VALUES ('test'), ('test3')
INSERT INTO #Data2 (Valor1,Valor2) VALUES ('test','test3'),('test2','test4')
GO
SELECT * FROM #Data1
SELECT * FROM #Data2
GO
INSERT INTO #Data2 (Valor1,Valor2)
SELECT Valor1, COALESCE (Valor2,Valor1) FROM #Data1
GO
SELECT * FROM #Data2
GO
DROP TABLE #Data2
DROP TABLE #Data1
```